# Where does DateTime.ToLocalTime() get offset

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a simple code:

```
System.DateTime dt = new DateTime(635267088000000000);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLocalTime());
```

I have changed Location, Format and System Locale in the Windows "Region and Language Settings", but the result didn't changed.

I have restarted computer.  I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system Timzone setting is in the "Date and Time" control panel, not the "Region and Language" control panel (and confusingly, that's also where the Keyboard language setting is, rather than the Keyboard control panel).

Answer (score 2):

Strangely... The code you have provided can't be aware of local info because you hasn't specified the kind of local. To get advantage of the conversion to the local or universal time you must specify the kind of `DateTime` object like this:

```
DateTime dtUtc = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime dtLocal = dtUtc.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", dtUtc, dtLocal);
```

This will output something like this:

```
22/2/2014 10:25:59 - 22/2/2014 14:25:59
```

Note that if you use `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow` they already have kind information as `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Utc` respectively.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.Kind);
dt = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine(dt.Kind);
dt = new DateTime(635267088000000000);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Kind);
```

Output is:

```
Local
Utc
Unspecified
```

Explore this example.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(635267088000000000); // same as DateTimeKind.Unspecified
DateTime dtUtc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime dtLocal = dt.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", dt, dtUtc, dtLocal);

dt = new DateTime(635267088000000000, DateTimeKind.Local);
dtUtc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
dtLocal = dt.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", dt, dtUtc, dtLocal);

dt = new DateTime(635267088000000000, DateTimeKind.Utc);
dtUtc = dt.ToUniversalTime();
dtLocal = dt.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", dt, dtUtc, dtLocal);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but your example give me "22.02.2014 11:55:47 - 22.02.2014 17:55:47"

Comment: If I use DateTimeKind.Local as the second parameters, than dtUtc and dtLocal will be the same.  Looks like the DateTimeKind.Utc is default value for second parameter.

Comment: `I don't know why, but your example give me "22.02.2014 11:55:47 - 22.02.2014 17:55:47"` that's mean you in UTC +6 time zone.

Comment: `If I use DateTimeKind.Local as the second parameters, than dtUtc and dtLocal will be the same.` Where are you confused? If you have specified `DateTimeKind.Local` your datetime is local then converting it to local will give same result because it is already local.

Comment: I was confused by your answer :) Why do I need to pass second parameter (DateTimeKind.Utc) in this line DateTime dtUtc = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);  If I skip it nothing change (as I see)

Comment: When the kind of `DateTime` is unspecified, on conversion it treats doubly. Look at example in updated answer.